# App is clashing after showing activity_main.xml only

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, logcat

[This is the first part of logcat of My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxGR1.png)

[This is other half part of my logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OrUc.png)

I have made Notes app and it is clashing. Can anybody help with it. I am also adding ss of kotlin file which is mentioned in the first ss of logcat.
[SS of kotlin file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W9RF.png)

Comment: You are casting AppcompactImageview to Button. That's the error. It means you have declared a button in the XML file. And assigned it to Imageview. Goto line number 30 to fix the error in Kotlin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I suggest you directly paste your code instead of adding screenshots. Not everyone can check out the images.

Coming to your error, it is because you are casting it wrong as specified in an error.

Check your line 30 in your `NotesRVAdapter`. Inside your `NoteViewHolder` you are casting it as `Button` while it is an `ImageView`

Change it as follows

```kotlin
val deleteButton: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button)
```

Comment: I will keep your suggestion in mind for next time. Thank you so Much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have some problem in your main activity ,probably put imageView in your layout and define button in your code
check again and make it right if its wrong